# Pytesseract does not recognize when it's just a letter

Tags: python, opencv, tesseract, python-tesseract

I need to recognize only one letter

But OCR does not recognize when it's just a letter

in this case I am trying to recognize the letter H but nothing shows up

What can I do to make it work?

```
from PIL import Image
from pytesseract import *
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('H.png',0)
edges = cv2.Canny(img,100,200)
img_new = Image.fromarray(edges)
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img_new, lang='eng')
print (text)
```

Comment: Can you attach the sample `H.png` and the corresponding canny edge output ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the following:

```
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img_new, lang='eng', config='--psm 10')
```

Comment: Hi. 
Can you explain why this should work (I have not tested by myself)?
Thanks

Comment: --psm 10 means: Treat the image as a single character. https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/Command-Line-Usage